# How to redirect default English content Item to Default website in Sitecore?

Tags: redirect

I am trying to redirect https://www.mydomain.com/en to my default site i.e. https://www.mydomain.com/en-US

I have tried with Sitecore module, it is working if i select any language other than en like en-In, en-AU but not with en.

I am trying with IIS redirection module with below rule

```
 <rule name="English Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/en?$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/en-US" appendQueryString="false" />
  </rule>
```

is there anything wrong in the rule? or any limitation from sitecore that we can not redirect protected language?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following rule:

```
<rule name="Default Language" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="en" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/en-us" />
</rule>
```

You don't need wildcard or regexes for matching exact url - just use `ExactMatch` pattern syntax - it will be microseconds faster, but remember that it's compared for every request.

Moreover, what is passed to the rule url condition, never starts with '/' character, so if your url is `http://www.mydomain.com/en`, only 'en` will be compared with url condition.

I tried it on my local Sitecore instance and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit the beginning / in your `match`, which is why Marek Musielak's answer works for him. He also changed the `patternSyntax` to `ExactMatch`, which would be equivalent to:

```
<rule name="English Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^en$" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain.com/en-US" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to update. Your solution did worked. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent! Could you please accept the answer, then? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @JitendraGhanekar Please mark this answer as accepted as this answer solved your problem.